# Stuck in GIMP's Text mode

Tags: gimp

I entered text and afterwards, I can't select anything else. I tried right clicking over the text and selecting Layer > Layer to Image Size.

This got rid of the bounding box over the text but I can't select anything else. Before I made the text if I selected the rectangle select tool, I could click anywhere on the map to null the selection, then drag a rectangle and start cutting and pasting, bucket fill, pencil etc..

None of these operations work now.

Comment: If you hide the _text_ layer from the *layers* dialog (Ctrl + L if there is no layers dialog), are you able to work as normal?

Answer (score 0):

In Gimp there is always an active tool, so just select another tool (Measure or Move, if you want something innocuous).